# Merge only if two consecutives lines startwith at python and write the rest of text normally

Tags: python-3.x

Input

```
02000|42163,54|
03100|4|6070,00
03110|||6070,00|00|00|
00000|31751150201912001|01072000600074639|
02000|288465,76|
03100|11|9060,00
03110|||1299,00|00|
03110||||7761,00|00|
03100|29|14031,21
03110|||14031,21|00|
00000|31757328201912001|01072000601021393|
```

Code

```
prev = ''
with open('out.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if prev.startswith('03110') and line.startswith('03110'):
            print(prev.strip()+ '|03100|XX|PARCELA|' + line)
        prev = line
```

Hi, I have this code that search if two consecutives lines startswith 03110 and print those line, but I wanna transforme the code so it prints or write at .txt also the rest of the lines

Output should be like this

```
02000|42163,54|
03100|4|6070,00
03110|||6070,00|00|00|
00000|31751150201912001|01072000600074639|
02000|288465,76|
03100|11|9060,00
03110|||1299,00|00|3100|XX|PARCELA|03110||||7761,00|00|
03100|29|14031,21
03110|||14031,21|00|
00000|31757328201912001|01072000601021393|
```

I´m know that I´m getting only those two lines merged, because that is the command at print()

```
03110|||1299,00|00|3100|XX|PARCELA|03110||||7761,00|00|
```

But I don´t know to make the desire output, can anyone help me with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# I assume the input is in a text file:
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    splited_line = [line.rstrip().split('|') for line in my_file] # this will split every line as a separate list
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(splited_line)):
       try:
         if splited_line[i][0] == '03110' and splited_line[i-1][0] == '03110': # if the current line and the previous line start with 03110
            first = '|'.join(splited_line[i-1])
            second = '|'.join(splited_line[i])
            newLine = first + "|03100|XX|PARCELA|"+ second
            new_list.append(newLine)
         elif splited_line[i][0] == '03110' and splited_line[i+1][0] == '03110': # to escape duplicating in the list
            pass
         else:
            line = '|'.join(splited_line[i])
            new_list.append(line)
       except IndexError:
          pass

   #  To write the new_list to text files

    with open('new_file' , 'a') as f:
      for item in new_list:
         print(item)
         f.write(item + '\n')
```

Comment: Your code join the lines, but I´m getting a duplicate line of the first 03110. Your code join the lines but preserve the first 03110, I wish like the output. Did I made myself clear?
Can you help me?

Comment: Ok it should work fine now. I forgot to add `elif statement`